# Can you use a Krasnogorsk lens (from the 16mm movie camera) on a Sony NEX camera?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, old-lenses, sony-nex

I would love to try and adapt the lens from my 16mm camera *Krasnagorsk* onto my *Sony NEX* bodies (3 or 5).

The lens I am referring to can be seen on this picture, it is a *f 1.9 Zoom Lens*:

[image]

I found links to adapters on eBay, but often have a hard time knowing what accessories will work and which ones won't (most "old lens to new bodies" adapters I have bought in the past have given so-so to mediocre results).

I would love to know if someone has tried to pair these two together, either a Sony VG-30 type camera which has E-Mount or one of the smaller photo cameras from the NEX range.
And ideally, a link to see some results!

Comment: Is the lens Meteor-5? M42 screw-mount?

Comment: @IliahBorg I don't have the camera with me at the moment, but this is the lens: http://retrothing.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/krasnogorsk3.jpg
If you tell me what this lens is called, I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The lens is Meteor-5-1 or Meteor-5. Both are 1,9/17-69, covering ~10.2×7.6 mm. Difference is that v. 5-1 is standard M42, with standard register (M42×1/45.5), and any adapter will work (mind the coverage!), while v.5 is a unique bayonet mount.

Comment: Ok thank you @IliahBorg ! Do you have any pictures of these mounts? I can't tell you unless I see them. Have you tried for yourself to mount these on a NEX?

Comment: Give me couple of days, optical measurements show that the lens should have much shorter register, close to 15mm. That would not work with standard adapters.

Comment: @IliahBorg any luck? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, standard adapters are useless. It is indeed 15mm register.

Comment: @IliahBorg can you explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: @inkista I really disagree with the most voted answer on that page for a multitude of reasons (call them "creative differences"), so I'd rather keep it specific. Also since it doesn't answer the question at all, I don't think it's a duplicate. Every complex lens / body combination could have its own question.

Comment: @fabrice-d: what Iliah Borg said is that the a standard M42-SonyE adapter should be 30,5mm shorter than it usually is. M42 is a 42mm thread placed at the distance 45,5mm from the sensor (register distance), Meteor5-1 is not a common M42 objective.

Comment: Thanks Pinhollow Euri! Then maybe material limitations would prevent this type of combination. I'm still investigating and excited at the possibility of doing this, but only have seen a couple of adapters online that claimed to be explicitly designed to combine this lens with this camera...

Comment: The closest off the shelf thing is what is usually sold as a super slim/ultra slim/short build M42 adapter (which is just a thin ring), combined with M42 extension tube segments and/or M42 helicoid(s). If the lens actually has ~15mm register *from the mounting flange*, even that won't get you to infinity. If it has ~15mm from the rear element, that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Krasnogorsk-3 has a Pentax M42x1 mount, though may be some models with Krasnogorsk bayonet mount.

The lens mounted is the Meteor 5-1. f1.9 /17-69mm
[image: Meteor 5-1. f1.9 /17-69mm]

You can mount the M42 lens in mirrorless cameras, with the appropriate adapter. This lens was designed for 16mm film, so there are considerations using it on bigger frames.

Seems not suitable for SLR as the back element protrudes. [Meteor-5-1 info @ allphotolenses.com](http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_1481.html)

[Meteor 5-1 17-69mm Cine Lens Test on Panasonic GH4 (vimeo)](https://vimeo.com/95805981)

Comment: Is the focal flange distance the same as for a 35mm camera M42 lens?